# php echoing angle brackets

Tags: php

I want to display text on the page, the text should look like this:

`<sometext>` ... but when I echo this, nothing appears!!

How ca I do this?

Comment: What? Give us something to work with. If you echo "<sometext>"; it should work. So please give us a snippet of your code.

Comment: BTW, those are not *square brackets*, they are *less than* and *greater than*. Sometimes people call them angle brackets.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A "page" is written in HTML, so `<` means "Start a tag".

You have to represent characters with special meaning in HTML using [entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.3.2).

You can write them directly, or make use of the [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) function.

```
echo "&lt;sometext&gt;";
echo htmlspecialchars("<sometext>");
```

Comment: if I`m using the `<` in email headers, shall I use the htmlspecialchars() function?

Comment: No. Email headers are not web pages. You must conform to the syntax of whatever header you are dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `&lt;sometext&gt;`.

If that text is coming from user input, you should definitely use `htmlspecialchars()` on it, to help prevent XSS.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the browser assumes it is an unknown tag. If you want the browser to show it, use:

```
echo '&lt;sometext&gt;';
```

or use the `htmlentities` function like so:

```
echo htmlentities('<sometext>');
```

Comment: `s/htmlentities/htmlspecialchars/`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `htmlentities()` to convert the HTML metacharacters into something that will display properly.

Comment: I'd go for `htmlspecialchars()` as `htmlentities()` does way more than needed in this case